# Как лучше выявить дубликаты в массиве String

Tags: c++, unrealscript

Работаю со строками в псевдо C++ скриптах, Unrealscript, и столкнулся с тем что нужно выявить дублирующие строки в массиве, т.е строку с одним и тем же контентом но под другим индексом, нужно как то определить.

Массив примерно выглядит так:

```
array<string> strArr;
```

в нем уже заранее имеются строки, примерно такого содержания

```
strArr = {"Temporarily","Increases","Momentarily", "Chance","Increases","Temporarily","Momentarily"};`
```

Если итрировать каждое из слов через цикл for

```
for(i = 0; i < 100;i++)
{
 debugf("string %s"strArr[i]);
}
```

, как тогда сопоставлять прочитанные строки, на дубликат - с теми которые идут в очереди ?

Создать массив дубликат, и добавить еще 1 цикл внутрь основного ?
Т.е вот так

```
for(i=0;i<strArr.length;i++)
{ strArr[i];
   for(k=0;k<strArrDub.length;k++)
   {
   if(strArr[i]==strArrDub[k])

   }
}
```

И получится так что если к примеру основной цикл [i] остановился на 7-мом элементе `Momentarily`, то второй цикл [k] пройдется по всем от 0 до первого вхождения 'Momentarily', которое уже будет под индексом 3, и тогда сработает проверка, не так ли ?

если да то, нельзя ли это как то представить по другому либо как то ускорить, в Unrealscript есть псевдо hashmap, и не очень работают некоторые функции масивов.

Comment: Вам нужен определенный порядок строк в массиве? Их можно переставлять? Что надо делать с дублями?

Comment: @Harry, пока что я хочу понять как правильнее будет - находить эти дубликаты, и если дубликат найден то -к  нему можно просто добавлять счетчик, т.е +1,+2,+3, важнее то как определить их, то что я описал по идее сработает - но, может есть что то по лучше ?

Comment: @Harry хотелось бы сделать что-то вроде итератора массива, Ar.begin ar.end, т.е чтобы можно было добавлять определенные условия - к примеру в массиве 15 объектов, я ставлю условие if(counter>6 && counter<8) то тогда мы прочли объекты от 0 до 6(т.е 7), и к примеру объект под индексом 3 является дубликатом для объекта под индексом 7, тогда я делаю итирацию по прочитанным строкам - пусть их будет 7, и добавляю праверку - если объект сохраненного массива == Объект итрируемого, то объект вывести.  выглядит примерно так. http://pastebin.com/ixiLTEG3 , как это лучше представить ?

Comment: Простите, что обнадежил своим вопросом, но я как-то не заметил, что это вопрос НЕ по C++... А в скриптах я ничего ответить не могу.

Comment: @Harry - Unrealscript, Это C++ в упрошенном виде, там почти весь синтаксис из C И С++ имеется, кое что в обрезанном виде, может можно как то в упрошенном(Но правильном) виде это сделать ?

Comment: Ну, в чистом C++ я бы отсортировал строки, а потом смотрел на соседние - не одинаковы ли. Если надо удалить дубликаты - использовал бы алгоритм `uniq`. Как минимум в вашем варианте двух циклов я бы использовал один и тот же массив - зачем второй? - и второй цикл начинал бы с `k=i+1`.